# Spacewalk - creating software channels

Tags: centos, spacewalk

Is there a way to assign one child channel to multiply parent channels, basically I don't want to duplicate channels (EPEL):

How can I achieve something like this:

```
CentOS 6 - x86_64
|- CentOS 6 x86_64 - Updates
|- EPEL 6 x86_64

Scientific Linux - x86_64
|- Scientific Linux - x86_64 - Updates
|- EPEL EL 6 x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have one child channel (same label) assigned to two parent channels. However, you can have one repository in sync with two child channels.

If you want to achieve something such as what you mentioned:

1. Create both the parent channels, CentOS6_x86_64, and ScientificLinux_x86-64
2. Create first child channel with label epel_6_x86_64, and choose CentOS6_x86_64 as your parent channel.
3. Create second child channel with label epel_el_6_x86_64, and choose ScientificLinux_x86_64 as your parent channel.
4. Create a repo named epel6_repo ( I assume you already did that from manage repositories tab)
5. Now, go to each of the child channels' page, select repositories tab, select the same reposotory epel6_repo for both the channels, update repositories, and sync.

You'll achieve what you wanted. Here, we are accessing the same repo from two parent channels, with different names.

Answer (score 0):

Orrr...

Maybe just consider adding the EPEL repo to the C6-64 and SC6-64 channels.  No need for a child channel, anyway; just glue in the repo.

This may, admittedly, only be good for small internal repos where you KNOW that all machines will want access to this repo.  So, maybe consider including your spacewalk-client repo in your channels, but for a repo like VMware OSP RPMs that will only be valuable for your virtualized hosts you'll want to do the full up child-channel-and-repo route.